# looping future event posts from custom field date in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to loop some posts, that have a custom field called "WooCommerceEventsDate" containing a date in format (j F Y).
What I'm trying to achieve is only looping posts that are after the current date. I have tried just about any solution I've seen online and I just can't get it to work. Right now the loop takes all posts, and not just the ones that have a date after today.

Here are my arguments so far:

```
$today = date('j F Y');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       =>  'publish',
    'meta_key'          => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,
        )
    )
);
```

Can one of you guys spot where this is going wrong, and why the arguments arent filtering?

For clarification 
`echo get_field('WooCommerceEventsDate');` echoes: "2 August 2016".

I am unable to change the output of WooCommerceEventsDate in my backend. I can only do it in my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `type`  in `meta_query`.

`type` => (string) - Custom field type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.

```
$today = date('j F Y');
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'meta_key'          => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today,
                 'type'     => 'DATE',
            )
        )
    );
```

For more information Check this http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/ line no 141 'meta_query'

> EDIT

For Change date format of `WooCommerceEventsDate` Go to `plugins/woocommerce_events/js/events-admin.js` find this function

```
jQuery('#WooCommerceEventsDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'd MM yy'

});
```

Change with this

```
jQuery('#WooCommerceEventsDate').datepicker({
                //dateFormat : 'd MM yy'
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

**Note::I am not sure this change affects to another or not.**

Comment: Before adding type => date, it shows all posts without date filtering. If i add date it shows none. I checked the dates set in the custom fields. They are definitely after today.

Comment: @EmilØstervig check this link for more information http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: Thanks but i have already seen the different types of arguments. I have tried pretty much all of them. What i'm asking in this question is why my arguments aren't filtering the posts. I'm not asking for a complete list of available arguments.

Comment: @EmilØstervig you need to change your date format ('j F Y') to ('Y-m-d') then my code working fine.

Comment: Can i change the 'WooCommerceEventsDate' field in a variable, and then use that variable as the key? It couldn't seem to make it work using variables in the key.

Comment: @EmilØstervig which plugin used for "WooCommerceEventsDate"

Comment: Thank you so much, i have been looking for where that information was parsed. It makes it a lot easier when i have control over that field!

Comment: @EmilØstervig You're most welcome. I'm glad it helped